# Assets not loaded

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I have problem, my assets not loaded - 404 Not Found

`"nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.6@dev"`

I executed `php bin/console assets:install` and `php bin/console assets:install --symlink`

**Locally** works, but on the **test server** don't works... could someone know some magic about this ?

locally
Request URL:
http://symfony.localhost/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js - loaded correct

On the test server
http://11.11.11.11/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css not loaded

and returned error

```
in /var/www/symfony/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/View/ViewHandler.php (line 163)
Format 'html' not supported, handler must be implemented
```

I checke files in `/var/www/symfony/public/bundles`, looks like correct, files present in `nelmioapidoc`. What I missed ?

fos rest configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener:
        service: my_body_listener
    unauthorized_challenge: "Basic realm=\"Restricted Area\""
    access_denied_listener:
        # all requests using the 'json' format will return a 403 on an access denied violation
        json: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json ] }
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ json, xml, html ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            jsonp: false
            xml: false
            rss: false
        mime_types:
            json: ['application/json', 'application/x-json']
    routing_loader:
        default_format:  json
    exception:
        enabled: true
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException': 400
        messages:
            Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: true
            Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: true
```

But I guess it not relation with fos rest. Because this is assetic resources, it should be loaded without handling. And for most important thing, locally woks without any problem

Another thing, maybe problem with server. I use Docker with nginx image. This my conf nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
  client_body_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
  client_body_buffer_size 256k;
  client_body_in_file_only off;
}

daemon off;
```

and host

```
server {
    server_name symfony.localhost;
    root /var/www/symfony/public;


    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

statat for file in test server (I add chmod 777 -R vendor/nelmio)
when executed `assts:install --symlink` (the same case when propel value, without `--symlink`)

```
/var/www/symfony # stat public/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
  File: public/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
  Size: 154006      Blocks: 304        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 1038685     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-03-26 08:43:56.025515192 +0000
Modify: 2020-03-25 16:45:47.667069605 +0000
Change: 2020-03-26 08:42:59.921460536 +0000
 Birth: -
```

For compare example from local (where works correct)

```
    /var/www/symfony # stat public/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
  File: public/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css
  Size: 154006      Blocks: 304        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 5797767     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-03-25 16:12:02.252465289 +0000
Modify: 2020-03-25 16:10:42.100983234 +0000
Change: 2020-03-25 16:10:42.100983234 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: What have you tried to check for that problem? If the file is really present on the file system, but not loaded, can you share your `.htaccess` (or similar configuration)? Looks like an existing file is served through PHP instead of directly be served by the webserver

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Is `/bundles` a symlink or a proper copy of all the bundle's files? What does `stat /var/www/symfony/public/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css` return?

Comment: I update question

Comment: If you use Docker, do you use seperated containers for the PHP processes and the nginx server itself? How are these connected? Can you bash into the nginx container to check whether the file in question is present there?

Comment: thank you, you was right, problem was with nginx config host, yesterday directory renamed for project and forgot rename it in volumes for nginx image

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem with a little change in nginx default.conf like:

```
set $root_path '/var/www/{YOUR_SYMFONY_PROJECT}/public';

root $root_path;

location ~* ^/(bundles)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
}
```

I hope I have helped you